Change language of app by using buuton inside
I want to change the application language from English to Russian by pressing a key. After watching a bunch of guides I came up with this form:
Button(onClick = {
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("ru"))
    
},
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
    Text(stringResource(id = R.string.Feet))
}Button(onClick = {
            AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("ru"))
            
        },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.Feet))
        }

I didn't forget to create a new XML file with new langua and add
android:localeConfig = "@xml/locales_config">
Chat GPT GPT didn't say anything
